# I have a question regarding a signed binary calculation

Tags: binary, logic, signed

Suppose I have two signed binary which is:

A: 1100
B: 1000

And I want to subtract B from A.

After 2's complementing B, this would be:
1100 + 1000 = '1'0100

I thought that there would be an overflow from this because the sign for A and B is negative while the answer is positive, but my worksheet answer key says otherwise.

My question is, will the overflow be 1  or is the answer key mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

There's no overflow in this computation.

- `1100` is `-4` decimal.
- `1000` is `-8` decimal.
- `-4 - (-8) = 4`
- So the result is `0100`, without any overflow. (All the values involved are representable as signed-4-bit, which covers the range `-8` to `7` inclusive.)

Note that subtraction never overflows (neither overflow, nor underflow) if the operands have the same sign, which is the case here.

It appears you're confusing the extra bit at the end of the addition with determining whether overflow happened. This simply isn't the case in general; for each operation there are different rules to determine if an overflow/underflow happened. Here's a good paper to read, which details the exact conditions under which underflow/overflow occurs for signed and unsigned binary arithmetic of bit-vectors: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/z3prefix.pdf

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks! So I believe that knowing the range for all signed # of bit would be enough to detect an overflow?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean; but in general if the "mathematically precise result" fits into the target size, then yes; there won't be any over/under-flow. The point is that computing the mathematically precise result" can be really expensive. (Imagine multiplication of large-bit vectors), so techniques have been developed to determine if overflow/underflow exists without doing the exact operation. The paper I linked has a very nice summary of these results.